# How to save Intents

Tags: android, android-intent, save

I have launcher buttons in my app that can be set by the user to either launch an application or a shortcut.  The problem Im having is how to save those intents and then reload them when the application is closed and restarted.  I was saving two strings for the package name and activity name and recreating the intent which works for simple application launches but doesnt work for things that have extra data like DirectDials or Saved Navigation locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the Intent class's `toUri()` method? All the data for the Intent should be in the URI.

Comment: Thank you that got me on the right direction, now I just need to figure out how to get the name and icon out of the intent and ill be good to go